# Making LaTeX document with fixed dimensions

Tags: formatting, dimensions

I am trying to create a document that has a *fixed dimension* of 1024 pixels x 512 pixels. Here is an attempt so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{siunitx} % for SI units (e.g. C, degree)
\usepackage{bm} % bold for some math symbols
\usepackage{xcolor}

\geometry{
paperwidth = 1024px,
paperheight = 512px,
margin = 1cm
}

\begin{document} \sloppy

Here is an example, the \textit{identity matrix} is given by 
\begin{align*}
    \mathbf{I} = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1
    \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

This keeps the document at the fixed width, but obviously, the text is too small. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Could you give some background info on the purpose of such a document?

Comment: @leandriis I am hoping to make these into a png (can be converted) and to share on twitter as an image. The maximal size that an image on Twitter can appear without cropping is 1024 x 512 pixels.

Comment: Why not manually increase the font size using `\large` or similar commands?